# How do I prevent anchor from filling entire containing div of element?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am developing a website that has a mobile nav when it gets below a certain size.

I want the user to be able to click on the hamburger icon to expand the menu.

The issue I'm having is that the clickable area is much larger then the actual image that the anchor tag wraps around.

Here is a screen shot to show what I mean.

[image: example]

I am using the chrome extension pesticide to outline the different elements in blue.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="row fullWidth">
    <div class="small-6 large-2 columns" id="logoContainer">
        <img src="img/vi_tie_icon_for_site.jpg" alt="VoIP Innovations" height="50" width="85" />
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 large-8 columns">
        <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
            <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation"><img src="../img/burger_icon.png" /></a>
            <a href="#" title="Hide navigation"><img src="img/x_icon.png" /></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Titanium</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 large-2 columns" id="loginContainer">
        <p class="logIn">Log In</p>
        <p>Sign Up</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS

```
/*NAV BAR STYLES*/
#nav
{
    /* container */
    img{
        margin-top:25px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
}
    #nav > a
    {
        display: none;
    }
    #nav li
    {
        position: relative;   
        padding:15px;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        list-style:none;
        font-family:$googleFont;
        font-size:1.25em;
    }

    #nav li .active{
        /*ACTIVE STATE GOES HERE*/
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
        #nav li .active:hover{
            color:inherit;
        }


@media only screen and ( max-width: 1023px )
{
    #nav
    {   
        z-index:10;
        position: relative;
    }
        #nav > a
        {
        }
        #nav:not( :target ) > a:first-of-type,
        #nav:target > a:last-of-type
        {
            display: block;
        }

    /* first level */

    #nav > ul
    {
        background:black;
        height: auto;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
        #nav:target > ul
        {
            display: block;
        }
        #nav > ul > li
        {
            width: 100%;
            float: none;
        }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you need to make the "hamburger" anchor an inline-block. Block elements take up the full width of the parent by default.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JH4rS/)

```css
@media only screen and ( max-width: 1023px )
{
    #nav
    {   
        z-index:10;
        position: relative;
    }
        #nav > a
        {
        }
        #nav:not( :target ) > a:first-of-type,
        #nav:target > a:last-of-type
        {
            display: inline-block;
        }

    /* first level */

    #nav > ul
    {
        background:black;
        height: auto;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
        #nav:target > ul
        {
            display: block;
        }
        #nav > ul > li
        {
            width: 100%;
            float: none;
        }


}
```

Comment: nvm. I figured it out. This was my change.         #nav:target > a:last-of-type
        {
            display: inline-block;
        }

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

width: auto;
display: inline-block;

..for the anchor element to size itself to the size of the text inside. Took me 30mins of bashing the keyboard to remember this today lol